# WSO2 IS - UserStoreException while configuring mongodb-user sore

Tags: mongodb, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to configure MongoDB user store as our primary user store in WSO2 Identity Server v5.9.0 following steps provided in below GITHUB repo:

[MongoDB user store extension](https://github.com/wso2-incubator/identity-userstore-mongodb)

```
[user_store]
type = "database"
class = "org.wso2.carbon.mongodb.user.store.mgt.MongoDBUserStoreManager"
connection_url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/wso2_carbon_db"
connection_name = "wso2_admin"
connection_password = "test123"
```

I tried running the wso2server.bat after copying the mongodb.user.store.mgt-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in both the paths

```
latestwso2\repository\components\plugins
latestwso2\repository\components\dropins
```

[WSO2 Identity Server Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khBbI.png)

[WSO2 Identity Server Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0HnK.png)

Please let me know what else do I need to configure to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the bundle is not getting activated. [1]
The extension that you are using may not be compatible with IS-5.9.0. It's compatible with IS-5.5.0. So the versions should be upgraded relevant to the dependency versions used in IS-5.9.0[2]

[1].https://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-debug-wso2-carbon-products-using.html

[2].https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/v5.9.0/pom.xml